# Count a categorical field in a YTD manner - PowerBI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am stuck on an issue where I would want to show counts for a categorical field based on the till date `Date` column as per the selected slicer:

**Input:**

Consider 2 tables:

**First:** table named `Table`

```
   ID Rule  Start Date    End Date  Year  Month    Uniq
    1    A  01-01-2020  01-01-2020  FY20      1  FY20_1
    2    B  01-01-2020  01-02-2020  FY20      1  FY20_1
    2    C  01-01-2020  01-03-2020  FY20      1  FY20_1
    1    A  01-01-2020  01-02-2020  FY20      1  FY20_1
    2    B  01-02-2020  01-02-2020  FY20      2  FY20_2
    3    C  01-02-2020  01-04-2020  FY20      2  FY20_2
    4    D  01-02-2020  01-03-2020  FY20      2  FY20_2
    5    E  01-02-2020  01-03-2020  FY20      2  FY20_2
    2    B  01-03-2020  01-03-2020  FY20      3  FY20_3
    3    C  01-03-2020  01-03-2020  FY20      3  FY20_3
    4    D  01-03-2020  01-04-2020  FY20      3  FY20_3
    5    E  01-03-2020  01-04-2020  FY20      3  FY20_3
    6    E  01-03-2020         NaN  FY20      3  FY20_3
    7    E  01-03-2020         NaN  FY20      3  FY20_3
```

**Second:** Table named `Calendar_Table` (`Uniq` column is the common key)

```
   Year  Month    Uniq
   FY20      1  FY20_1
   FY20      2  FY20_2
   FY20      3  FY20_3
```

**Problem Statement:**

I have 2 slicers `Year` and `Month` coming from the `Calendar _Table`. Based on the selected Month and Year combination, I want to show the break down of counts of the `ID` column from the `Table` table. However the counts should not be filtered for that specific month, rather until that month(like a YTD). Also there is a condition that I need to consider here.

> For a specific month selected, take all rows until that month based on `Start Date` column, and filter `End Date` for only next month onward (filter out all till that month) , this will give 4 rows for February.

Example: If Slicer for Month 2 is selected , i would select the first 8 rows from `Start Date` (Jan and Feb) and then filter from `End Date` any date after Feb(Match,April,so on..) , then i would like to show the distribution of `Rule` based on count of `ID` column.

**Current try**:
A measure that gets the start date based on the Month selected:

```
StartDt = VAR test_var = MAX('Table'[Uniq]) 
return CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK('Table'[Start Date],1),FILTER(Calendar_Table,Calendar_Table[Uniq]=test_var))
```

Then apply the condition explained above:

```
YTD_RULE_Breakup = var stdt = [StartDt] 
return CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[ID]),FILTER(ALL('Table'),'Table'[Start Date]<=stdt && 'Table'[End Date]>stdt))
```

**Current Output:**

When I pull this in a card, i get the correct value (4) , however I am not able to get the distribution of the Rule based on this measure:

[image]

**Expected output**:

My expected output is :

[image]

I would appreciate if someone can help me doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the YTD_RULE_Breakup measure, try replacing FILTER(ALL('Table') with:

```
FILTER(ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Rule])
```

While the FILTER(ALL) works succesfully if we are only interested in the grand total. We can use ALLEXCEPT with the [Rule]-column, to make sure the measure will count the measure for each Rule-column also.